# switching from dual boot windows/kubuntu(kernel panic) to windows/ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, kubuntu

I currently have a dual boot setup windows/kubuntu. amd slimbook pro x.

Recently was prompted to update kubuntu as it will stop being updated. After running the updater it seemed to fail. File explorers would not open but web browser would, overall unusable. Next I rebooted to recovery and ran dpkg and defaulted to 'No' on any changes of modified config files by me or script and booted and everything seemed great. A pop up then followed saying a restart would be needed to finish installation. After restarting I ended up with a kernel panic. Recovery mode also is a kernel panic. There are no other kernels to choose from. Just a note the windows partition is working fine.

I would like to switch to ubuntu. I know there are some specific drivers for the device hardware and Im just unsure of where to begin since the kernel panic incident. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The drivers for Kubuntu & Ubuntu are all the same. What version of Kubuntu? Do you have good backups. If converting DE, you may not want to restore most of the hidden (.dot) files in /home as those would be for Kubuntu, and not for Ubuntu. But you may want some apps you manually installed  & all your data. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have a backup :( link to pastebin here https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sc92qYQCbX/      I'm happy to keep the kubuntu if it works just trying to get back up and running. I was thinking of switching because there is a more active community here for help. I'm very new to linux, very much appeciate the help!

Comment: @oldfred does the autorepair seem safe or do you recommend a clean install?

Comment: I am not seeing anything wrong with configuration, other than you are not connected to the Internet. I only use Kubuntu, now, but other than different DE there is no difference in boot, kernel or drivers with Ubuntu. Not familiar with Slimbook. Is Kubuntu the original install of 22.04.1? That is what I am using on multiple computers, but I primarily use Ethernet. Needed an adapter (Ethernet & 3 USB ports) for new Dell that only had 2-USB-C & one USB3 ports. What WiFi chip do you have? Check WiFi configuration.

Comment: @oldfred card is Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a), I ended up doing a clean install the bootrepair didnt work. looks like there is a brief error that flashes before it boots but seems to be working fine. In the GRUB menu Ubuntu at the top is the correct boot. the previous kernel panic is still listed as Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) (on /dev/nvme0n1p4) as well as the advanced options for it. is there a command line way or another way to delete those easily?

Comment: So is new install in a different partition? You can backup any data in old install if any, and delete partition. Then os-prober will not find it. If UEFI entries, you can use efibootmgr to delete old UEFI entries. I have multiple installs, some old, some new. So I add the boot stanzas I want from grub, copy into 40_custom and then turn off os-prober in /etc/default/grub. "GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true" With grub 2.06 that may now be the default setting.

Comment: @oldfred I just did an install from usb on the same partition. Kind of a noob so I don't know if that was not a good move. Just trying to clean things up and keep it working :/

Comment: That should be the preferred method, if you have good backups and know not to format partition, so your data, but not settings would be preserved.  Not sure what old boot info you are then seeing?

Comment: looks like it automatically created a new partition? running fdisk current display  /dev/nvme0n1p1      2048     34815     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p2     34816 489023487 488988672 233.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p3 489023488 490072063   1048576   512M EFI System 
/dev/nvme0n1p4 490072064 776079967 286007904 136.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p5 776081408 976771071 200689664  95.7G Linux filesystem
@oldfred

Comment: You cannot format comments, best to just post in question. run this report just to see details, not sure what partition is what. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/7hKs67pxDH/  here is the current boot info. The clean install is working there is an error right before it boots to kubuntu desktop that flashes very quickly but everything is working as far as i can tell. I just want to get rid of the kernel panic version that shows up in the grub menu but im not sure how to do it.

Comment: You show two installs, p4 & p5. The default boot is not to p5, see line 194 which has UUID of install in p5. So it looks like you can delete p4, unless you want to experiment with making repairs. When you install, you can use Something Else to choose same partition. And you always want to have good backups to make reinstall & restore easy.

Comment: @oldfred thank you so much for the help I will indeed keep backups from here on out!